# Dispatcher hidden from IntelliSense in VS2017

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I've just started using VS2017 and noticed that in WPF the `Dispatcher` object no longer shows in IntelliSense when editing inside a window.

Looking at the definition I can see:

```
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>
Public ReadOnly Property Dispatcher As Dispatcher
```

However the option to hide this is not available for Visual Basic:

[image]

Now it's quite possible this is a bug in VS2017 but in case it's not any ideas?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a change in VB.NET because I see it in C#?

Answer (score 2):

this will display `TheDispatcher` function in IntelliSense:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function TheDispatcher(dispatcherObject As DispatcherObject) As Dispatcher
    Return dispatcherObject.Dispatcher
End Function
```

Comment: This is more of a work arround than a fix, but not a bad idea. Only problem is this has to be included in every project I create (or a referenced dll)